# Creating a link to subversion repository on Liferay site?(widget?)

Tags: svn, version-control, widget, liferay

I have created a liferay website and one of the major requirements it to have a user interface to the subverison so users can have direct access to the subverision files directly on the Liferay website? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check out WOL portlets?

http://www.liferay.com/web/brian.chan/blog/-/blogs/introducing-world-of-liferay

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1058530